# Access javascript object directly through DOM traversing with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, traversal

I'm working on a simple client side interface where I have a jQuery object that I want to access directly when clicking on a hyperlink. Simplified code:

```
<div class="controls">
    <div class="score">
        <a class="button" href="/add">Add points!</a>
    </div>
</div>


$(".controls").myControls();

$.fn.myControls = function() {
    return $.extend(this, $.myControls).initialize();
}

$.myControls = {
    initialize: function() {
        this.scoreElement = $("div.score", this);
        this.linkElement  = $("a", this.scoreElement);

        this.scoreElement.score = 0;

        var _this = this;
        this.linkElement.click(function() {
            _this.clickHandler(this);
        });
    },
    clickHandler: function(element) {
        var scoreElement = $(element).parent();
        scoreElement.score = 1;
    }
}
```

Explanation: `.controls` element has `.score` element which doubles as a container for score information (`this.scoreElement.score`). When I click on a link within the `.score` element, I find the parent element, which is the same element in the DOM as `this.scoreElement` and try to set its `score` property to 1. Obviously, this won't work, as the local `scoreElement.score` property in the `clickHandler` method is "undefined".

***So here's my question:** is there a simple way to access my `this.scoreElement` object directly through traversing the DOM with jQuery?*

Surely I can check if `this.scoreElement == $(element).parent()` in some way and then access the right property in my `this.scoreElement` object, but direct access would be more elegant and robust. Is this possible? Am I going at it the wrong way? Thanks!

PS: Ignore the fact I use `parent()` to find the `scoreElement`, I only use it to illustrate my problem. Unless it is part of the problem, in that case don't ignore :)

Comment: It's all very convoluted. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: What I'm actually building is a simple dice game where I can 'hold' any die by clicking a link related to the die; this link is a child of the DOM element that makes up the die. I think I'm better off building a separate object for each die, which makes my problem go away, but I'd still like to learn a bit by getting a good solution/answer to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it's certainly possible to use your own 'control-object' to store the related data, I usually prefer to rely on jQuery doing it - with [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) method, like this:

```
$(this.scoreElement).data('score', 0); // in initialize()
$(this).parent().data('score', 1); // in clickHandler()
```

This approach allows me to scale more easily, as I never have to fear 'overlapping' issues, using a single 'control' object rather than object-for-element.

Comment: Ok, that would work and sounds like a solid solution, but sadly less readable. Can you make a case for your 'scaling' argument, a simple example perhaps? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would think that if you used jQuery's proxy function for your click handler, you then could just go this.scoreElement inside of clickHandler and you wouldn't even need to traverse the DOM. Like this:

```
$.myControls = {
    initialize: function() {
        this.scoreElement = $("div.score", this);
        this.linkElement  = $("a", this.scoreElement);

        this.scoreElement.score = 0;

        this.linkElement.click($.proxy(this.clickHandler, this));
    },
    clickHandler: function(event) {
        var element = event.target;
        this.scoreElement.score = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: That would be a great answer, but (maybe I wasn't completely clear in my question) `this.scoreElement` is not just a single element, but it relates to the link that was clicked. So, the `event.target` (the link element) should point to "its" `scoreElement`, which is my problem: where does that `scoreElement` live and how do I access it directly? Your answer only solves my problem if `this.scoreElement` is a single object existing in `$.myControls`. But thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

After progressive simplification (and storing the score slightly differently) I get the code below, in which `scoreElement` is discovered once per `.controls` div, then held in a closure to make it available to its corresponding click handler. You could alternatively use `.closest()` - see commented out line.

```
$.fn.myControls = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        var scoreElement = $("div.score", $(this));
        scoreElement.data('score', 0);
        $("a", scoreElement).on('click', function() {
            scoreElement.data('score', 1);//get scoreElement from closure formed by the outer "each" function.
            //$(this).closest(".score").data('score', 1);//alternative to the line above, not requiring closure.
        });
    });
};
```

Call as in the question with:

```
$(".controls").myControls();
```

This is so trivial and unidimensional it doesn't really warrant, in its own right, a jQuery plugin. Unless there was some compelling reason for a plugin (eg. reuse or the need for closely related methods), then I would phrase it as follows :

```
$(".controls").each(function() {
    var scoreElement = $("div.score", $(this));
    scoreElement.data('score', 0);
    $("a", scoreElement).on('click', function() {
        scoreElement.data('score', 1);//get scoreElement from closure formed by the outer "each" function.
        //$(this).closest(".score").data('score', 1);//alternative to line above, not requiring closure.
    });
});
```

That's the same code with the plugin wrapper removed and attached directly to the same base jQuery object.

And if you really wanted, you could write the whole thing in three lines as follows:

```
$(".controls").find("div.score").data('score', 0).find("a.button").on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest(".score").data('score', 1);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I agree with everything you say, the core of the solution here is jQuery's `.data()` method which raina77ow also stated. I'll go with his answer if you don't mind. Ofcourse my actual code is a bit more complex than what I wrote in here as an example but you make a good point that this particular bit doesn't warrant a plugin. But then again, it does make code more readable and scalable.